# Parametric colors

Tags: macros, color

Is it possible to define colors as variables? for example, instead of write

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\rmfamily\huge\bfseries\color{violet}}% <<====== TITLE COLOR
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

I want to write

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\rmfamily\huge\bfseries\color{chapterTitleColor}}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

where `chapterTitleColor = violet` (or any color I want)

I need this in order to create a config file and read colors as well as other parameters from there.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I think writing in the preamble `\colorlet{chapterTitlecolor}{violet}` should do the the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\colorlet` command from `xcolor` in your preamble to give specific names to colours you want to use – like this:

```
\colorlet{chapterTitlecolor}{violet}
```